# Cursor and query

Tags: android

case R.id.buttonTest: {

```
        String[] projection = {DbTest.NAME};
        String selection = "_id = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(1) };

        Cursor c = sqdb.query(DbTest.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs ,null,null,null);
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbTest.NAME));
        textView1.setText(name);
        }
        break;
```

logcat:

Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

What's the problem? I do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to do use:

```
c.moveToFirst()
```

This is because a cursor starts with an index of -1 until you use this command. You can also use the result (boolean) to determine if the cursor is empty.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
c.moveToFirst()
```

*For more details:* [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29)

Hope this helps

Comment: What is different about your answer?